# Git removes all my previous commits

Tags: git

I had made 1000+ lines of changes in about ~17 new files. Then I was handed a task that required an emergency fix, so I committed my changes. Pulled, which resulted in some merge conflicts and resolved them taking theirs. Now I made my changes for that fix, and made two separate issues. Then when I wanted to push to remote, I did not want to include the previous commit so I ran git rebase -i. And picked the last two commits.

Now after push, all my changes and those new files are gone. What have I done wrong? I don't now even see my commit when I do git log. Is there a way I can go back to that commit?

Comment: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Comment: Likely you have reset to a base commit at some point of your merge resolution. Your previous commits are still on disk, use `git reflog` as @MarkLakata suggests. Also you may find useful a graphical tool like `gitk --all` to visualize commit graph.

Comment: *"resulted in some merge conflicts and resolved them taking theirs"* -- it seems this is where you dropped some of your work.